# FileNotFound error when renaming files using shutil.move in Python

Tags: python, shutil

I'm in chapter 10 of Automate the Boring Stuff, and one of its activities suggests renaming files in order when one is missing (e.g., `Spam001.txt`, `Spam002.txt`, `Spam004.txt`, ...).

When testing the code with a `print()` call and commenting out the `shutil.move()`, the program does what I want it to do.

I first ordered the files using lists and the sort function. The first list (`order`) contains the original filenames in order, and the second list (`out`) are the correct filenames.

Filenames are `capitalsquiz1`, `capitalsquiz3`, `capitalsquiz4`... It skips the `capitalsquiz2`, so I expect `capitals3` to be renamed.

```
def fill_gap(folder):
    print(f'in {folder}')
    #create regex to find numbered filenames
    num = re.compile(r'^(.*?)((\d)?(\d)?(\d))')
    
    order =[]
    out = []
    #go through all the files in the folder
    for oldfile in os.listdir(folder):
        
            
        mo = num.search(oldfile)
            
        if mo == None:
                continue
            
        order.append(mo.group(2))
        
    order.sort(key = int)
       
    for i in range(len(order)):

        order[i] = mo.group(1) + order[i]
        out.append(mo.group(1)+str(i+1))
        
    print(order)
    print(out)
    
    for i in range(len(order)):
        
        
        main = os.path.abspath(folder)
        old = os.path.join(main,order[i])
        
        order[i] = out[i]

        new = os.path.join(main, order[i])
        
        print(os.path.basename(old))
        print(os.path.basename(new))
        print (f'renaming "{old}" to "{new}"...')
        #shutil.move(old, new) 
                
                
            
        
fill_gap(r'C:\\Users\Andrei\pyject\rand_quiz')
```

I've run it without the shutil.move and using print to check. It runs the way I want it to but when I add the shutil.move, it gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\shutil.py", line 825, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\Andrei\\pyject\\rand_quiz\\capitalsquiz1' -> 'C:\\Users\\Andrei\\pyject\\rand_quiz\\capitalsquiz1'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andrei\pyject\fill_gap_in_name.py", line 53, in <module>
    fill_gap(r'C:\\Users\Andrei\pyject\rand_quiz')
  File "C:\Users\Andrei\pyject\fill_gap_in_name.py", line 48, in fill_gap
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\shutil.py", line 845, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\shutil.py", line 436, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\shutil.py", line 256, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Andrei\\pyject\\rand_quiz\\capitalsquiz1'
```

Comment: My guess is you are missing out `.txt` in the file name

Comment: Thank you, it turns out I forgot to put the .txt on the file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Andrei\\pyject\\rand_quiz\\capitalsquiz1'
> ```

You have to take this message seriously. **No such file or directory.** Period.

Now, where is the error?

Here:

```
order.append(mo.group(2))
```

You didn't append the *file name*, but **only the matched part of it**.
Replace that command with

```
order.append(oldfile)
```

(FYI, I then tested your such a fixed code and I don't get that error message anymore.)

---

Yes, then you will get *other* error(s), but I don't want to spoil the fun from revealing and fixing them by yourself. ;-)